IPMI Idrac error, IANA PEN registry open failed: No such file or directory
Hello i have problem with IPMI idrac6. I have enabled IPMI on idrac web and i trying to connect but i getting this errors. Last time, one year ago, i fixed it, but i dont remember how, probably some settings on dell r610, i remember only i found ipmi is turned on somewhere but i cant find it now. Thanks for all help.
root@stats:~# ipmitool -I lanplus -H 192.168.0.112 -U root -P calvin chassis power status
IANA PEN registry open failed: No such file or directory
^C
SIGN INT: Close Interface IPMI v2.0 RMCP+ LAN Interfac

I searched all settings on dell r610, and all options on ipmitool. And i found nothing

This seems to be a known issue on Debian OS (see discussion here).
You can manually fix it by running the following command.
cd /usr/share/misc
wget https://www.iana.org/assignments/enterprise-numbers.txt

For the details, the issue seems linked to IANA changing its URL to retrieve the enterprise numbers. It should be fixed in the next Debian version (13). But there's still discussion around its fix for the current version (12).
